# Powershell - testpath from two different objects

Tags: powershell, csv

I have two objects in my Powershell script - **Application** + **Computer Objects** which are imported from a csv file

```
# import applications

$apps = @()
$apps = Import-CSV C:\Working\fcheck_v2\apps.csv 

# import computer objects

$compobj = @()
$compobj = Import-CSV C:\Working\fcheck_v2\compobj.csv
```

The structure of apps.csv is as follows:

```
appname          location      lob
Core             C$\errlog.ini  RESEARCH    
Blmbg            C$\errlog.ini  RESEARCH    
Blmbg2           C$\errlog.ini  RESEARCH        
MLFR             C$\errlog.ini  LEGAL
```

The structure of compobj.csv is as follows:

```
hostname        lob
192.169.226.2   RESEARCH
192.169.226.5   HR
```

How would I use testpath to check whether a particular application exists on a computer?

For example I would want to test that all the computer objects in the RESEARCH lob have the RESEARCH apps installed on the machines and print out the results in a table like this:

```
hostname        lob           core     blmbg     blmbg2     mlfr
192.169.226.2   RESEARCH      True     True      False      Frue
192.169.226.5   HR            True      N/A       N/A       N/A
```

If the machine passes *Test-Path* - then the status is set to **True**

If the machine fails *Test-Path*+ app needs to be installed (i.e. it is in the lob) - then the status is set to **False**

If the machine fails *Test-Path* + app doesn't need to be installed (i.e. it is not in the lob) - then the status is set to **N/A**

Thanks.

Comment: I assume that you mean Test-Path

Comment: Yup - I've updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some rough pseudo-code that will get you most of the way to what you're asking for. It should at least point you in the right direction. Re-reading your question, it may make more sense to re-order the loops and there is certainly some scope for optimization.

```
# foreach computer in compobj.csv
foreach $computer in $compobj
{
  # get the computers lob
  $computerLob = $computer.lob

  $lobApps = $apps | ? { $_.lob -eq $computerLob }

  foreach $app in $lobApps
  {
    # you will need to deal with authentication here 
    $result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer.hostname -Script { if (Test-Path $app.location) { return "True" } else { return "False" } }

    # Write out suitable output... 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please give mean example of what you mean by suitable optimisaiton?

Comment: Well for one, I determine each loop what the LOB apps are - this can easily be determined once upfront. Overall though, I'd focus on getting it working first and then look to optimize.